# can create new object based on a locally defined monodb schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, model

So the error is happening in "insertBook" when i call "new MakeModel()" since model returns a object.
This is the error code:

```
  throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
        ^
```

OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `book_model` model once compiled.

```
// this is the localhost db. 

const util= require("./util/db_con_discon")
const mongoose= require("mongoose")


// i return the model from the schema inside. 
function makeModel(){
    //vi) define a shema and save it in an bookSchema 
    const bookSchema= mongoose.Schema({
        book:String, 
        author:String,
        year:String 
    })
    //V) create a moddel named Book , using the defined bookSchema 
    const Book= mongoose.model("book_model",bookSchema)

    return Book;
}


async function insertBook(_book , _author, _year){
   ** const Book= new makeModel()** //this is what triggers the error code. 

    //vi) create new Book document oBject
    // await new Book(
    //     {
    //         book:_book,
    //         author:_author,
    //         year:_year
    //     }
    // ).save()
    // .then(()=>{console.log("saved the book")} )
    // .catch(()=>{console.log("failed to save the book")})

}

async function deleteDB(){
    await new makeModel().deleteMany({})
    .then(()=>{console.log("deleted the db ")})
    .catch(()=>{console.log("failed to delete the db ")})
}

async function main(){
    await util.connectDB()
    await deleteDB()

    await insertBook("Civilization","Tzu","1922")



    await util.disconnectDB()
}

main()
```

I've read that this can be solvedd by having an external file and importing this module into the files as needed but that would go against the instrcution of the assignment.

further more having and external file and calling New *return object* would be the same as having a local file that i call new makeObj(), no?

Please let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate a model once (usually it's done in a separate file):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 

const bookSchema= mongoose.Schema({
    book: String, 
    author: String,
    year: String 
});

const Book = mongoose.models.Book ||  mongoose.model("book_model",bookSchema);
```

Then, use it to create a new document:

```
const { Book } = require('path/to/book/model');

async function insertBook(_book , _author, _year) {
    await Book.create({
        book: _book,
        author: _author,
        year: _year
    })
    .then(()=> console.log("saved the book"))
    .catch(()=> console.log("failed to save the book"))
}
```